# using css selector nth-of-type doesn't work

Tags: css, css-selectors

There is a good example about using css nth-of-type selector http://codepen.io/mnafricano/pen/ltKvy, but when I run the example myself, I can't make it work. Can somebody point out what goes wrong in using the  nth-of-type

The html is
 `<h1 class='logo'>Google</h1>`
, and css is

```
h1.logo span:nth-of-type(1){
  color:#0089ab;
}
h1.logo span:nth-of-type(2){
  color:#d91821;
}
h1.logo span:nth-of-type(3){
  color:#ffac05;
}
h1.logo span:nth-of-type(4){
  color:#0089ab;
}
h1.logo span:nth-of-type(5){
  color:#88c406;
}
h1.logo span:nth-of-type(6){
  color:#d91821;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: Does `h1.logo` have any `<span>` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS here works, the trick is that there is some Javascript on that page which adds a `<span>` wrapper around each of the letters in "Google".

The CSS specifically is looking for the nth `span` inside of the `h1` with `class` "logo".

If you directly take the HTML and CSS, but not the JS the CSS rules will never match.

If you inspect the `h1`, you'll see the following:

```
<h1 class="logo">
  <span class="char1">G</span>
  <span class="char2">o</span>
  <span class="char3">o</span>
  <span class="char4">g</span>
  <span class="char5">l</span>
  <span class="char6">e</span>
</h1>
```

If you try that HTML instead, it should work as you expect.

Here's a [JSFiddle that may help](http://jsfiddle.net/ykue3/).